# Проверить наличие обработчика

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток! как можно проверить, есть ли определенный обработчик на элементе или нет?

Comment: в коде никак, в chrome dev tools можно посмотреть.

Comment: Если обработчики ставились через jQuery, то можно и проверить и получить их.

Comment: @lampa тоже не всё однозначно, $(parent).on(event,selector) вы так не поймаете.

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать $._data( element, 'events' );

Также советую посмотреть статью на эту тему: http://habrahabr.ru/post/200114/